# SSRS report snapshot not releasing transaction and causing tempdb bloat

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, alwayson

Scenario: I have a SQL Server 2016 Always On cluster for production data with a readable secondary used as the source of our reporting. I access this data from a different server where our SSRS installation resides. On this SSRS installation I have a given inefficient report that I decided to set up scheduled snapshots for so that end users only hit the snapshot and don't pound the readable production secondary.

Problem: Queries to Always On readable secondaries automatically are changed to snapshot isolation. When the scheduled SSRS report snapshot runs, it persists a transaction which causes versioning data to be stored in the TempDB. SSRS is not releasing these transactions when the next scheduled snapshot is taken and therefore I run out I inevitably run out of TempDb space if I don't kill the spids.

Has anyone else had this issue or know of an unresolved bug in SSRS that causes this condition?

I have to disable report caching/snapshots until I can solve for this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: You may want to change the source of the report to a materialized view or create a SSIS package that does the work.

Comment: That is what we are doing in the meantime. Once I discovered this I turned off the caching and snapshots and told the reporting guys they are going to have to build a package to pull the data periodically and persist it elsewhere unless/until we can get this squared up. Just not understanding why SSRS won't release the connection after the report data has been retrieved. It only does this with either the cached or snapshotted reports.

Comment: You may want to do a bit of a health check on the database report server.